# Custom form easyadmin 3 symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony5, easyadmin, easyadmin3

I need to create a custom form, I have created it with its twig template and I show it well, my problem is when submitting, I do not know what method it is sent to, I need to collect the data to go through it and save it in your table.

The main idea is to make a schedule and dynamically add input, add it to input [] and then in a function process this data and save it in your table.

Controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use...

class HorariosCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{

public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
{
    return $crud
        ->overrideTemplates([
            'crud/edit' => 'admin/horarios/edit.html.twig',
            'crud/new' => 'admin/horarios/new.html.twig',
        ])
        ;
}

public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
{
    return Horarios::class;
}
}
```

View:

```
            {# templates/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/layout.html.twig #}

        {# DO THIS: the '!' symbol tells Symfony to extend from the original template #}
        {% extends '@!EasyAdmin/layout.html.twig' %}

        {% block body_javascript %}
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $( document ).ready(function() {
                    var maxField = 9999; //Input fields increment limitation
                    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
                    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
                    var fieldHTML = '<div>' +
                        '<input type="time" name="field_name[\'lunes\']" value=""/>' +
                        '<input type="time" name="field_name[\'lunes\']" value=""/>' +
                        '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button">' +
                            '<img src="remove-icon.png"/>' +
                        '</a>' +
                        '</div>';

                    //New input field html
                    var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1

                    //Once add button is clicked
                    $(addButton).click(function(){
                        //Check maximum number of input fields
                        if(x < maxField){
                            x++; //Increment field counter
                            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); //Add field html
                        }
                    });

                    //Once remove button is clicked
                    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
                        x--; //Decrement field counter
                    });
                });
            </script>
        {% endblock %}

         {% block main %}
                 <form>
                 <div class="field_wrapper">
                     <div>
                         <input type="time" name="field_name['lunes']" value=""/>
                         <input type="time" name="field_name['lunes']" value=""/>
                         <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><img src="add-icon.png"/></a>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Añadir</button>
                 </form>


         {% endblock %}
```

When I submitted, I returned a 302

[image]